# Adding Domain\ to username

Tags: django, django-models

I'd like for my login page to have the user name function as it is, but for the record that is written to the database when a user authenticates with LDAP i'd like to have Domain\username with the user only entering username, the domain will never change so I could force it without looking it up.  However, all my other tables in my model are pre-existing tables with Domain\username as the primary key/foreign key.  How would I go about doing this?  Below is my

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.utils import timezone
from django.contrib.auth.models import (AbstractBaseUser,PermissionsMixin)
from django.db import models
from django.conf import settings
from django.forms import ModelForm


class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):



    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=7, unique=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=140)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    facility = models.CharField(max_length=140)
    jobdescription = models.CharField(max_length=140)
    positiondescription = models.CharField(max_length=140)
    coid = models.CharField(max_length=5)
    streetaddress = models.CharField(max_length=140)



    USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'

    class Meta:
        app_label = 'accounts'
        db_table = "user"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want your other models to point to "User" with a ForeignKey that is the format of `Domain\username`, correct ?

My first thought would be for your `User` model to have both a `ldap_username` and a normal `username` field. The `ldap_username` can be set as a primary key, and can be generated by overriding the model's save function.

Something like :

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.ldap_username = '{domain}\{username}'.format(
        domain='POTATOES', username=self.username)
    super(User, self).save(*args, **kwargs);
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed, thank you Brachamul, much appreciated.

Comment: Brachamul, if I want to include the formatted user in my view for this line.  How would I do it?  def applicationdetail(request, ntname, report_id):
    user = get_object_or_404(User, pk=self.request.user)                                                      Or could I just call formatteduser there?

Comment: What do you mean by "include the user in your view" ? Since you're getting the user object with `get_object_or_404`, you can just use `user.ldap_username` or `user.username` to access these values.

Comment: I'm not having issues getting the user information.  It's when I try to combine models in a template.  I can use owner = User.objects.get (formattedusername=request.user.formattedusername) which pulls in ABC1234.  That is the field that matches my USERNAME_FIELD so the data comes back.  If I change my USERNAME_FIELD TO formattedusername nothing returns.  If I use print owner.formattedusername it returns HCA\ABC1234.  However, when I try to filter on ntname = owner.formattedusername my report doesn't filter correctly even though the data in the existing database for ntname = HCA\ABC1234.

Comment: This is the view I'm using:    def profile(request):
    owner = User.objects.get (formattedusername=request.user.formattedusername)
    reportdetail = QVReportAccess.objects.filter(ntname = owner.formattedusername)
    print(reportdetail)
    args = {'user':owner, 'applicationaccess':owner.formattedusername}

    return render(request, 'accounts/profile.html', args)

Comment: portion of the template for report:        <h2>Current Access Application List</h2>
      <ul>
{{reportdetail.report_name}}
        <li>Application Name: {% for app in applicationaccess %}
             <input type="checkbox" name="report_name" value="{{ app.report_name }}" /> {{ reportdetail.report_name }}<br />
        {% endfor %}
        </li>

      </ul>

Comment: I created a new question here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47186073/values-not-being-passed-to-template-django-for-second-model